# PdfBox write Page to Image scales Signatures

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

when trying to create an Image from a signed PDF Page, the resulting image shows the signatures but the signatures are not displayed correctly.
For example, the original contains two signatures next to each other in the bottom section. 
In the resulting image the signatures look like they have been scaled up and are overlapping.
Furthermore, there's a signature in the top right corner. This signature looks scaled up in the resulting image and is cut off to the right. What is happening here? What am I doing wrong? I'm pretty new to working with PDFs on this level.

Hope that makes sense. Please see below for the differences (I've cut out other content).

Here's the code I'm using:

```
List<PDPage> pages = inputDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
PDPage page = pages.get(0);
BufferedImage image = page.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, PDF_RESOLUTION);
String fileName = "converted_image_" + (i + 1);
ImageIOUtil.writeImage(image, "png", fileName, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, PDF_RESOLUTION);
```

here's the original
[image: original]

and now the distorted version
[image: distorted]

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong. There are some problems with annotations appearances (and a signature is one) in the 1.8 versions. It is solved in the unreleased 2.0 version (which you can get with svn if you want), but the solution wasn't used in the 1.8 version because there were some risks left.

Comment: Nice. Let me give it a try.

Comment: Argh, ok. Major version increment does what it promises. I'm missing the convenient page.convertToImage . Do you have any docs at hand describing the transition?

Comment: No; the best is to look for the examples in the source code, there's a lot for every purpose. Rendering is done with new PDFRenderer(doc).renderImageWithDPI(pageNum, dpi)

Comment: Works. I've added that as answer. Looking at the new architecture, I doubt there will be a backport so those appearances would work in 1.8.x - didn't look on the exact changes or issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by  Tilman Hausherr, I was using the current 1.8.x stable release which has problems with annotations appearances. This led to the seen behaviour. Testing with the current 2.0 SNAPSHOT solves this problem.

Now we are eagerly awaiting the release of 2.x :)

From what I've seen, they totally reworked how creating images from a PDF(Page) should be done so I'm not sure about the probability of a backport.

Hope that helps for anyone else coming across this.

Comment: For what it's worth, here's the original Bug related to this behaviour. If I understand it correctly, it boils down to PdfBox not being able to handle the embedded TTFs correctly. The several workarounds provided in related tickets did not work for our special PDF. YMMV [Pdf Printing of text from embedded fonts](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-490)